# Wordpress theme implementation of owl carousel not stopping on hover

Tags: javascript, wordpress, owl-carousel

So I have an owl carousel slider, provided by the theme I'm using, but its not stopping autoplay on hover.

I have tried adding `animation-play-state:paused` to the `:hover` of the respective elements, but that didn't work.
I'm not much of a Javascript guy, so I don't really know how to proceed.

This is the carousel html:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-loaded owl-drag" data-dots="false" data-nav="true" data-items="3" data-items-laptop="2" data-items-tab="1" data-items-mobile="1" data-items-mobile-sm="1" data-autoplay="true" data-loop="true" data-margin="30">
```

The slider is otherwise working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add:

```
data-autoplay-hover-pause="true"
```

So you will get:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-loaded owl-drag" data-dots="false" data-nav="true" data-items="3" data-items-laptop="2" data-items-tab="1" data-items-mobile="1" data-items-mobile-sm="1" data-autoplay="true" data-loop="true" data-margin="30" data-autoplay-hover-pause="true">
```